# Apply percentage format with VSTO - multiply by 100 behind the scenes

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a piece of code that formats cell according to requirements:

```
        Range.Font.Italic = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        Range.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignGeneral;
        Range.NumberFormat = "0.0_%_);(0.0)_%;-_%_)";
```

And this code is invoked then button on custom ribbon is pressed. It's similar to percentage cell format. One more thing I have to add is multiplying the cell value by 100.
For instance

- cell value is set to 0.15, I click button and value changes to 15%.
- cell value is set to 2.5, I click button and value changes to 250% etc. (very similar to default Excel Precentage cell style)

However, if I do something like this:

```
        decimal result = Convert.ToDecimal(cell.Value);
        cell.Value = result * 100;
```

and user hits button multiple times, value is multiplied every time. Is there a way to specify something like display format, so that actual value is preserved and only displayed value is multiplied by 100? Or another way to prevent value from being multiplied multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need to multiply it by 100

If the cell has .15 then apply the formatting

Range.NumberFormat = "0.00%"

It will automatically change to 15.00 % and you don't need to multiply it by 100.

**FOLLOW UP**

An out of the box thinking... Why not hide the % symbol by setting the color of the % to white?

**VBA CODE**

```
Sub HidePercentage()
    Dim Temp As String

    Temp = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "0.00%")

    With ActiveCell
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Formula = CStr(Temp)
        .Characters(Start:=Len(Temp), Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: That's true. Unfortunately it automatically adds % character. And requirement is not to show it. This is why I have _ character before % in my NumberFormat.

Comment: If that is the case then see my amended post ;)

Comment: This is pretty out of the box :) THanks!

Comment: @dragonfly: Feel free to close this question if your query is solved :)

Comment: I didn't use it (ultimately), but it's a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way would be maintain a hidden sheet, Move original value, or maintain flag for that cell in hidden sheet on button click